# Connecting to IP camera using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to connect to my CP Plus IP Camera using opencv python.

Here is the code i tried:

```
import cv2
camera_ip = "192.168.1.23"
url = f'rtsp://{camera_ip}/live'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but it is giving me following error:

```
tcp @ 0x169517e0] Connection to tcp://192.168.1.23:554?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
[ERROR:0@0.269] global cap.cpp:164 open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): rtsp://192.168.1.23/live in function 'icvExtractPattern'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip_cam.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

I also tried changing url to below but still same issue:

```
http://192.168.1.23:8888/?action=stream
```

Comment: `Connection refused`: Are you sure your camera is in the same networks as where you run your script ? It this URL reachable ?

Comment: Yes, camera is in same network

Comment: This doesn't work on G5 and latest wifi 6

Comment: I dont know how your camera rtsp server respond when stream path is not correct, it should normally be an other error, but are u sure you have correct rtsp url like described online (https://camera-sdk.com/p_6657-how-to-connect-to-a-cp-plus-camera.html) for your vendor ? rtsp://viewer:pass@123.123.123.123:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0